# Installing Portable VirtualBox and Xubuntu on USB Drive

Tags: usb, virtualbox, xubuntu, usb-installation

I am trying to set up my Ubuntu environment per the recommendations of The Odin Project's installation setup (https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/prerequisites). I am trying to set up VirtualBox and Xubuntu to run from a USB Drive that way I can work on either my local computer or my work computer (and I want to install as little as possible on the work computer anyway.)

Currently, it looks like I have VirtualBox up and running through the setup drawn out at https://www.vbox.me/. I have created the virtual machine setup according to the instructions, and have the Xubuntu disc image file stored on the flash drive so that it's always with me. When I start up the virtual desktop however, I am given an error.

[image: Virtual machine startup error]

I am using a Sandisk 128GB Solid State Flash Drive and am trying to follow all recommendations on the Odin Project's page.

Comment: Looking in the log, I have a "Warning! Failed to load bcrypt.dll" that seems to be the start of the troubles when on startup. Would this be a file I'm missing or didn't get setup?

Comment: If there is a problem with bcrypt.dll then that is a Windows issue.  I'd double check to ensure all updates and patches from Microsoft are installed on your system before attempting to boot your virtual machine again.

Comment: I never had much luck with portable VBox. It always messed up VBox installed on the host computers. What worked for me was to do a Full install of Ubuntu to USB and install VBox on that. I have Win 10 running on this and can use ACAD, SolidWorks, SketchUp, MS Office, etc. It is slow on USB2 but workable on most USB3. If interested let me know and I will post an answer with details. I have not tried this with full disk encryption.

Comment: I'd like to know more about this solution; I'm just trying to follow the instructions on TheOdinProject as close as I can so if yours can work with that version of Xubuntu (though really I think it would be fine to use another; I've just never used Linux before), then I'm fine with it